# what is "that" for in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence I do not comprehend:

> Then, in the midseason promo… it is revealed **that** come March 9, when Season 3B opens, *Lost* looker Rebecca Mader will be playing… the Wicked Witch of the West!
> <sub>Source: [*Once Upon a Time* Midseason Finale Recap](http://tvline.com/2013/12/15/once-upon-a-time-storybrooke-vanishes-wicked-witch-of-west-season-3-recap/)</sub>

What exactly does the word “that” mean in this sentence?

Comment: It's possible that the adjunct *come March 9* is confusing you.  I would call this use of *come* a preposition, personally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [that] in such contexts, the word "that" doesn't actually *mean* anything at all.

This can be seen by noting that in that sentence above, the first instance of the word is entirely optional (much the same applies in *this* sentence, except stylistically it's far better to include it).

OED says of ***that***...

> Introducing a subordinate noun clause, as subject, object, or other element of the principal clause, or as complement of a n. or adj., or in apposition to a n. therein.
>   ...*generally held to have arisen out of the demonstrative pronoun pointing to the clause which it introduces.*

In practice, it's extremely unlikely a competent writer would omit "that" in OP's example. Its function is to alert the reader/listener to the fact that a noun phrase (the thing revealed) is coming next. In OP's specific context, that noun phrase is quite long and complex, so the "indicator" is useful. It could still be used (but would be far less *necessary*), with a more common introductory verb (***say*** instead of ***reveal***), and simpler "subordinate noun clause". For example...

> *John says [that] Rebecca is a witch.*

...where you could say "that" is a pronoun representing the statement/noun phrase "Rebecca is a witch".

---

As @snailplane astutely comments, the adjunct ***come*** March 9 might be confusing to some learners. It's just a stylised/dated/formal way of saying *when March 9 **comes*** (or to put it more simply, ***on*** March 9).

Comment: _That_, in this usage, is called a **Complementizer**, if anybody ever asks you what part of speech it is. And the clause it introduces is called a [Complement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complementtypes.pdf) clause.

Comment: @John: It might be a false memory, but I had the distinct feeling a similar question was asked a few weeks ago either here or on ELU, and [that(1)] you yourself had commented [that(2)] **that** doesn't exactly "mean" anything in such contexts. I couldn't find it though, which is why I posted an answer here. What I still don't really understand, though, is why my preceding *that(1)* seems to be far more "optional" than *that(2)*, even though they look syntactically equivalent to me.

Comment: Complementizers don't have any meaning, true. Neither do articles or auxiliary verbs; they're all part of the program, not the data. As far as deletion goes, they are syntactically equivalent, but by the time you got to [that(1)], you'd already deleted [that(0)] from the complement clause of _feeling_, and [that(1)] is coordinate with it, so there's a tendency to do similar things to coordinate clauses. The last one is the complement of _commented_, a different construction altogether. Moral: replace what's missing before analyzing a sentence.

Comment: @John: oic. (Neat slide into the "zero-based subscripts" programming convention, btw! :) I wasn't consciously aware of having deleted *that(0)* - but obviously my inner grammarian was, which is why he pressed me to do the same to *that(1)*. And even if I didn't know it, *he* knew *that(2)* was part of an entirely new construction. Thanks!